# Mule expression in logger component not valid xpath

Tags: xpath, expression, mule

I have an xml like this:

```
<order>
  <orderheader>
    <orderissuedate>1/11/2013</orderissuedate>
  </orderheader>
</order>
```

in the mule logger component set with INFO, i have a mule expression that tries to print out the orderissuedate 1/11/2013.

i use the expression:

## [xpath('/order/orderheader//orderissuedate')] which didn't work.

i also tried: #[xpath('/order/orderheader/orderissuedate/text()').text] that didnt work also.

can someone tell me what the correct xpath expression is.  i get this error message:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "/Order/OrderHeader/OrderIssueDate/text()"

I've tested these xpath expressions using online xpath checkers, and they seem to work.  thanks for your help.

Here is the original xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE Order>
<Order
      xmlns:core="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <OrderHeader>
    <OrderNumber>
      <BuyerOrderNumber>111111</BuyerOrderNumber>
    </OrderNumber>
    <OrderIssueDate>2013-06-28T08:40:12</OrderIssueDate>
    <OrderReferences>
      <AccountCode>
        <core:RefNum></core:RefNum>
      </AccountCode>
    </OrderReferences>
  </OrderHeader>
</Order>
```

and the error output from mule:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "/OrderIssueDate"
    at org.mule.module.xml.el.XPathFunction.call(XPathFunction.java:50)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELFunctionAdaptor.call(MVELFunctionAdaptor.java:38)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1011)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:987)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:377)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:143)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.optimize(ASTNode.java:159)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:115)
    at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:85)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:113)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:942)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:214)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:163)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:142)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:220)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager$2.match(DefaultExpressionManager.java:481)
    at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:153)
    at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:130)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:477)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:436)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor.log(LoggerMessageProcessor.java:89)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor.process(LoggerMessageProcessor.java:71)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProcessor.process(DataMapperMessageProcessor.java:132)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "/OrderIssueDate"
    at org.mule.module.xml.expression.AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.java:144)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:311)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:230)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:186)
    at org.mule.module.xml.el.XPathFunction.call(XPathFunction.java:43)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.dom4j.Document, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:252)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:355)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:313)
    at org.mule.module.xml.expression.AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.getPayloadForXPath(AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.java:154)
    at org.mule.module.xml.expression.AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator.java:115)
    ... 64 more
ERROR 2013-08-26 00:40:49,893 [[mule_egc2].EGC_FlowFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.dom4j.Document, mimeType='*/*'}".
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-236
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.dom4j.Document, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper:252 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.dom4j.Document, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:252)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:355)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:313)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<logger message="OrderIssueDate is #[xpath('//Order/OrderHeader/OrderIssueDate').text]" level="INFO" />
```

Make sure that to use the case correctly for your XML elements hierarchy. You have `order` in top XML while `Order` in lower one and so on

Answer (score 2):

the xpath expression that would work according to me is `#[xpath://orderissuedate]` To print using the logger you should use something like `<logger message="#[xpath://orderissuedate]" level="INFO"/>`

Comment: hmm that didn't work, don't you have to specify the nested levels to get to orderissuedate? /Order/OrderHeader//orderissuedate?

Comment: No xpath specifies you can directly use `//` to get the appropriate tag directly,which version of Mule are you using?Can you please share your complete xml if it has namespaces? also you can try `#[xpath('//orderissuedate')]` to match the type of expression suited to your mule version.

Comment: After OrderHeader dont give two `//` give a single `/` as you have mentioned in your comment.

Comment: im using mule 3.5.0. i tried two forward slashes or one forward slash i think it might be a namespace issue.

Comment: Can you post the error log and the complete xml if it has any namespace prefixes?

Comment: Your mule config may also help

Comment: From your error log i can see that the payload is not of xml type so i think you'll need to convert the payload to xml format using a transformer

Comment: hey raul, i think thats the reason.  but i have used datamapper to convert the xml to a map.

Comment: So are you applying the xpath expression before mapping or after maping that will decide whether the payload is suited for the expression.I just know what datamapper is havent used it much.So as i already suggested your mule config can tell me more.

Answer (score 0):

From the conversation on one of the answers  the following solutions hould work.

```
<logger message="Value of Order Issue Date  #[xpath('//OrderIssueDate').text]"  level="INFO" />
```

It would be better if the DTD of the Order is also provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your original XML seems to have namespace :-

```
xmlns:core="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

So, if you need to extract the value using Xpath from your original XML, you need Mule namespace manger :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XML+Namespaces

Other than that if you want to extract the value from your XML you shown above, you can use the Mules latest Xpath3 available right now from Mule version 3.6 which is easy to use :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath
Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help:

```
#[xpath3('//order/orderheader/orderissuedate/text()')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mule latest xpath3 like this if you are getting namespaces

## [xpath3('//*:orderissuedate/text()')]